# drag and drop - to specific box

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

how i can do a drag and drop functionality that only permit the movement for a specific box?
basically the same effect that is showed in the dojo demo.

There is possible to make with html5 or jquery?

[demo - dojo](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojo/tests/dnd/flickr_viewer.html)

Comment: Are you open to using jQueryUI? That library would make your life much easier for effects like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery by itself doesn't provide UI Components out of the box. To get drag and drop and other sort of UI interactions and components, [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) is the library to use with jQuery. In HTML5 this is achievable but you will still want the jQuery version for backwards compatibility.

Best of Luck